# Given a list of bounding boxes, how can I find the coordinates of a polygon that covers all boxes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, bounding-box

I am drawing ellipses over an image using Pillow from a list of bounding boxes. I want to be able to draw a polygon over them like in the (poor) example image below:

[image: Polygon over ellipses]

However, I am a bit lost on how to get the polygon coordinates or get only the outer bounding boxes from that list and calculate the polygon from there. Any tips/help is appreciated.

Comment: you can use union of these geometries. please check the python `shapely` module

Comment: Sounds like what you want is the convex hull - try searching for that.

Comment: @kaya3 That is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!